# jquery "on" issue on dynamic item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".files").on('change', function() {
            $('.file_fiels').append('<li><input type="file" name="attachments[]" multiple="multiple" class="files" /></li>')
        }); 

    })
```

and HTML

```
<ul class="file_fiels">
<li><input type="file" name="attachments[]" multiple="multiple" class="files" /></li>
</ul>
```

which means, when somebody add an item to input, another input type should show up.

Its working perfectly with the first input type, it doesn't work with the input that is created when I add on item on the first input type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use on event delegate for dynamically added elements

```
$('.file_fiels').on('change', '.files', function() {
   $('.file_fiels').append('<li><input type="file" name="attachments[]" multiple="multiple" class="files" /></li>')
});
```

[read more](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) about on delegate events

Comment: As I was in the process of answering this you can see this working here http://jsbin.com/ihegoh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Since parent `<ul>` element is static, you can use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(".file_fiels").on("change", ".files", function() {
    $(".file_fiels").append("<li> ... </li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always used `.live()` for dynamic items, it worked pretty much flawlessly for me.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.9.1, 'live' is deprecated on this version